# How to select first row with where clause on second row

Tags: sql

I am using SQL through an API tool that supports only basic SQL, not any special SQL features supported by SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL etc.

I have a SQL that returns data like:

[image: swql_result]

Is it possible to make this SQL as sub query and pull result that would look like:

[image: expected_final_result]

If I have `col_2 = 'str2' AND col_3 = 'act'` I'll get one row from the pair of green rows.

But in my result I want the row from green pair that has col_2 = 'str_1'.

I know this is weird but I want to see if that's possible. I was not able to think of any way to do this. I tried putting the SQL that pulls first result in `SELECT t1.col_1, t1.col_2, t1.col_3 FROM (<SQL_1>) t1 WHERE...` and variants of it but couldn't get anywhere near the expected solution.

Pairs of green rows will always have same string in col_1.

Comment: This is not really possible to answer unless you specify the data or functionality you are talking about.  Most functionality in the databases you mention is either SQL standard or a slight variation thereof.

Comment: Thank you your response @GordonLinoff. I agree I should have improved my question but by the time I was working to do that following your response, I got couple of answers, so I had to test those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `exists` does what you want. This is standard sql, that all relational databases that I can think of support:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    col2 = 'str_1'
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = 'str_2' and t1.col3 = 'act'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am marking this as answer as your response came first. Also it works perfect in SQL environment, but the API tool (SWQL) I am using didn't allow EXISTS so I used `1 IN` instead of `EXISTS`. May be because of this change it's now complaining about use of `t.col1` in `EXISTS`. I'll figure that out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

The comments are spot-on: don't send photos, faxes or TELEXes of your data.
Post something that can be executed in a database.
Make use of modern technology like [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) and share your problem.

Concerning your question:
it reads like you want to select certain groups/sets of your data with a filter on `COL_3 = 'act'` and then return records from those groups/sets that have `COL_2 = 'str_1'`.

That's easy to do with standard SQL:

```
WITH selector
(col_1, col_4)
    as (SELECT 
            col_1, col_4
        FROM
            data 
        WHERE col_3 = 'act')
select
      d.col_1
    , d.col_2
    , d.col_3
    , d.col_4
from 
    data d
    inner join selector s
      on (d.col_1, d.col_4)
       = (s.col_1, s.col_4)
    and d.col_2 = 'str_1'
;
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xfbwBDJdPGdTNDuK4hSz1R/1).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wish I could mark 2 responses as answer :-) or upvote more than once. Your response works perfect in SQL environment, but the API tool (SWQL) I am using doesn't allow WITH :-(. So I am trying to figure out a workaround. Thank you again!

Comment: You can always place the content of CTEs (WITH clause) into sub-selects. In this case, you would put the *selector* query in brackets where the `JOIN` condition currently has the word "selector".

Comment: Great! That worked like a charm! I changed it exactly as you suggested and it solved my problem. Can't appreciate enough!